# Using :after and :hover:after button in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a button which is animated using :after and :hover:after CSS. Tried numerous ways to get it to work in IE but cannot find a work around. May be because the empty content:"", or the transition, but even without the transition is doesn't work. Any help / explanations is greatly appreciated.

```css
button.bttnStyle1 {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.bttnStyle1:after,
button.bttnStyle1::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  content: "";
  -o-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
}

button.bttnStyle1:hover {}

button.bttnStyle1:hover:after,
button.bttnStyle1:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  -o-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease, height 0.2s ease;
}

button.bttnStyle1:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button.bttnColorGreen {
  color: #69e0b1;
}

button.bttnColorGreen:after{
 background-color:#69e0b1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="bttnStyle1 bttnColorGreen">BUTTON</button>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/benneb10/pen/pjRMqj?editors=110)

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow: visible;` to your `button`. Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108735/pseudo-elements-ie10-button#answer-18250000).

Answer (score 0):

Solition:

CSS border radius need an actual border to be defined. Overflow also needed to be visible and everything works.

```
button.bttnStyle1:after,
button.bttnStyle1::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5rem;
    width: 0rem;
    height: 0rem;
    line-height:0;
    border-radius:1rem;
    content: "";
    -o-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease, height 2s ease-out;
}

button.bttnColorGreen:after,
button.bttnColorGreen::after{
    border:1rem solid #69e0b1;
    background-color:#69e0b1;
}
```